# I am tying MQTT jmeter sampler plugin but it is throwing NullPointerException

Tags: jmeter, mqtt

```
2014/12/10 15:39:52 INFO  - jmeter.gui.action.Start: Stopping test 
2014/12/10 15:39:52 INFO  - jmeter.threads.JMeterThread: Stopping: Thread Group 1-1 
2014/12/10 15:39:52 WARN  - jmeter.threads.JMeterThread: Interrupting: Thread Group 1-1 sampler: MQTT Subscriber 
2014/12/10 15:39:52 WARN  - jmeter.protocol.mqtt.sampler.SubscriberSampler:  java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.fusesource.mqtt.client.CallbackConnection$8.onSuccess(CallbackConnection.java:501)
    at org.fusesource.mqtt.client.CallbackConnection$8.onSuccess(CallbackConnection.java:490)
    at org.fusesource.mqtt.client.CallbackConnection.disconnect(CallbackConnection.java:514)
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.mqtt.client.MqttSubscriber.close(MqttSubscriber.java:298)
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.mqtt.sampler.SubscriberSampler.interrupt(SubscriberSampler.java:164)
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.interrupt(JMeterThread.java:631)
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.ThreadGroup.tellThreadsToStop(ThreadGroup.java:392)
```

Using mosquitto client I am able to subscribe and publish. But on Jmeter its not wokring.

Thanks, In advance

Comment: I downloaded the plugin from https://github.com/tuanhiep/mqtt-jmeter

Comment: Can you show your configuration of sampler ?

Comment: subscriber: Provider URl: tcp://<host>, client id= xyz, random suffix length=100, list topic= xyz, "One connection per topic",  QOS atleast once, timeout 10000

Comment: You can try this MQTT jmeter plugin : https://github.com/hemikak/mqtt-jmeter

Answer (score 0):

It's a bug in the plugin you're using.

Try this more up to date plugin:

- https://github.com/hemikak/mqtt-jmeter

Comment: Can you add anymore information, like a link to the issue report for the problem?